# Easier way to search my activity

Tags: discussion, feature-request, search

On SO when I want to filter search results to only include my activity, I can enter **user:1442874** in the search field along with the other search criteria.  I would use "1442874" because that's my internal userid.  My problem is that that's an id that i never really use or think about as I always refer to myself by my display name, "Chris Gerken".

So that makes manually entering a search involving only my activity a bit difficult.  Is there some way that I can search for my activity without having to remember or lookup my internal userid?  If not, should that be something the royal we can add to SO? Perhaps some special keyword that means "user: the user that's currently logged in"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could simply use `user:me` within your search, which as the same effect. All of this is outlined within the [Search Options](https://stackoverflow.com/search) page.

For future reference, I know of 2 ways to reach the Search Options page. Once you perform a search, it is linked to on the results page with the title "See our search tips!".

[image]

Furthermore, the particular option listed above is also mentioned within the FAQ under the header ["How do I search?"](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#searching), which at the end also contains a link to the Search Options page.

Comment: Very cool.  Now can you tell me how I would have navigated to that page?  I was looking for that page but couldn't find it.  Thx much.

Comment: hmm.. now it's telling me I have to count to 10 before accepting this answer.  I'll get back to it in a bit.

Answer (score 4):

As [Bart has pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147859/easier-way-to-search-my-activity/147860#147860), you can use the `user:me` to search for your post.

Alternatively, if you're lazy like me and want to save a few keystrokes, simply click on your username in the top bar. This will bring you to your profile page, and lo and behold, the search box is pre-populated with`user:<your uid>`. Example:

[image: click to go to profile]

When profile loads, search field is pre-populated with user id:

[image: ready to search own posts]

You're now ready to start searching for your posts. (Pro Tip: <kbd>Tab</kbd> once to shift focus to search box)

**Bonus tip:** When viewing another user's profile, the search box will contain their user id. That's a quick way to search posts of other users.

Comment: Freehand hands? I can't compete with that!